# LaTeX Error: File `suffix.sty` not found

Tags: tables, r, sweave, bigfoot, tinytex

I would like my R Sweave file to run smoothly in Rstudio. I have tried to compile the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,natbib}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage[color=blue!30!white,textsize=small,textwidth=28mm]{todonotes}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=2.0cm,top=2cm,right=3.2cm,bottom=3cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=-10pt, position=top} %farskip=-10pt,
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
%\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\begin{table}[!htb]
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{0.5cm}} c    @{\hspace{0.5cm}}  c }
% \begin{tabular}{SSS}
 \hline
  & Pooled coefficients &  Pooled standard error  \\
  
  \cline{2-3} \\[-2mm]
Intercept   &   
$1$ &  $2$ \\ \\[1mm]

$Age$ & 
$1$ & $2$ \\ [1mm]
 
Birthweight & 
$1$ & $2$ \\ [1mm]

Cronic health condition & 
$1$ & $2$ \\ 
 
BMI & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Gross motor skill & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Sibling & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Parental BMI & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

SES & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Family structure & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Self-regulation & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Psychological difficulties & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Emotionality temperament & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Activity temperament & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Eas\_soc & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Shyness temperament & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Parenting stress & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Cognitive performance & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Sleep duration & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Play frequency & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Parental sedentary behavior & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Parental sports club membership & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

pa\_cat\_comb21 & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Transport to childcare & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Parental involvement in child physical activity & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Parental tobacco use & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Parental alcohol consumtion & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Time outdoors & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Fixed toys & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Portable toys & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Days at childcare & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Living area per person & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Neighborhood safety & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Dog & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Season & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

Region & 
$1$ & $2$ \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:coefficients_and_standard_errors} The caption for the table}
\end{center}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Which I expected to output a table with text in the first column and 1 and 2 in the second and third column (I will use R output when I get it to work). Instead, I get the following error

```
LaTeX Error: File `suffix.sty` not found.
```

I have downloaded the Bigfoot package, but I am not sure if everything is located where it should be. The log file is as follows:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.5.5)  13 MAY 2021 07:58
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Make_table_example.tex
(./Make_table_example.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count175
\c@section=\count176
\c@subsection=\count177
\c@subsubsection=\count178
\c@paragraph=\count179
\c@subparagraph=\count180
\c@figure=\count181
\c@table=\count182
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 105.

(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2021/03/18 v5.0k Graphics/color driver for xetex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen139
\Gin@req@width=\dimen140
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2020/02/24 v1.2b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 147.
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip49
\fb@frw=\dimen141
\fb@frh=\dimen142
\FrameRule=\dimen143
\FrameSep=\dimen144
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/alltt.sty
Package: alltt 1997/06/16 v2.0g defines alltt environment
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen145
))
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen146
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count183
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count184
\leftroot@=\count185
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count186
\DOTSCASE@=\count187
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box47
\strutbox@=\box48
\big@size=\dimen147
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count188
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count189
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count190
\dspbrk@lvl=\count191
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count192
\column@=\count193
\maxfields@=\count194
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen148
\alignsep@=\dimen149
\tagshift@=\dimen150
\tagwidth@=\dimen151
\totwidth@=\dimen152
\lineht@=\dimen153
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip53
\bibsep=\skip54
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count195
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/bm.sty
Package: bm 2019/07/24 v1.2d Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
\symboldoperators=\mathgroup4
\symboldletters=\mathgroup5
\symboldsymbols=\mathgroup6
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 141.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bm on input line 209.
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(/Users/Tinius/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acronym/acronym.sty
Package: acronym 2020/04/17 v1.47 Support for acronyms (Tobias Oetiker)


! LaTeX Error: File `suffix.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.47 \newif
           \ifAC@footnote^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1880 strings out of 478893
 23562 string characters out of 5864781
 316003 words of memory out of 5000000
 21788 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403438 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 68i,0n,74p,275b,40s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

I run on a Macbook pro mid 2014 on Big Sur with the latest R and Rstudio. I am not sure about the latex setup as I am a noob in setting up things on my computer.

Thank you in advance! By bachelor thesis needs this :D

### Edit

Still do not work, unfortunately.

I have done what is suggested below and applied those changes to the example above.

- set the preferences in accordance to the first answer
- removed `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
- removed `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}`

The logfile is also changed to what is produced when using the new setup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you meant by "I have downloaded the Bigfoot package" but you don't need to do that manually if you check the option "Use tinytex when compiling .tex files" in RStudio's global options. Then RStudio will call the **tinytex** package to compile `.tex`, and missing LaTeX packages will be installed automatically.

[image: Compile .tex with tinytex in RStudio]

Comment: Hi, I now tried setting everything as you have them here as well as changing the two top settings. Yet I get the same error as above: 
`! LaTeX Error: File `suffix.sty' not found.` and 
`Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tinius About the warning:  just remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.  About the error:  you have not  the package `suffix`, or it is not correctly installed in a searchable path. If you are using `knitr` (as show this answer) you must also remove `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}`. With these changes your MWE work without problems for me.

Comment: @Fran I have now done what both of you proposed, it still does not work. I have commented out the two things you suggested I should remove and set up my preferences according to the proposal in the answer. This resulted in the log output in the post above. 

Did you mean in your comment that if I use knitr the accessibility of the suffix.sty file is not relevant or does the suffix.sty file still has to be downloaded in an accessible path? If so, this might be the problem.

Comment: @Tinius Your code  is now compilable with bot knitr and Sweave. A missing LaTeX package never is irrelevant. Neither it is irrelevant  to load  a bunch of packages that are not used in the example,  as  `acronym` (that require the package `suffix`). This is a perfect  example of why the minimal example should be really *minimal*.

Comment: @Fran Thank you! Now I commented out a bunch of stuff and I get an output. I have never used Sweaver before, so my advisor provided me with the example and stated that it worked. I could not imagine that loading packages would be a problem. Is it a problem because I use tinytex, but load packages that only would be necessary if I used something more "advanced" than tinytex?